# Error 500--Internal Server Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config

Tags: java, maven, jsp, servlets, weblogic

I am getting the following error while deploying the war file in weblogic server.I have created this by using Maven.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JstlUtils.exposeLocalizationContext(JstlUtils.java:97)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView.exposeHelpers(JstlView.java:135)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:211)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:184)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3750)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3714)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2283)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2182)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1491)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:252)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

I have the jstl-1.2 in lib and jstl-1.2 in weblogic too.But getting the same exception.

I have also tried removing the jstl-1.2 from war lib folder.Even though getting the same Exception.

What could be the reason?

This is my pom

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>se.jo.joassivosWebApp</groupId>
  <artifactId>MApp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>MApp Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
 <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
 <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
 <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
 <groupId>antlr</groupId>
 <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
 <version>2.7.7</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
 <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
 <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
 <version>3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
 <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
 <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
 <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
 <version>3.2.6.ga</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
 <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
 <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
 <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
 <version>1.6.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
 <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
 <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>log4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
 <version>1.2.12</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
 <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
 <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
       <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
       <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
      <version>10.2.0.2.0</version>
</dependency>
 
  </dependencies>
<!--   <build>
    <finalName>MApp</finalName>
  </build> -->
  
<build>
        <finalName>MApp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/xercesImpl-2.0.2.jar,WEB-INF/lib/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar</packagingExcludes>
                    
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-XX:-UseSplitVerifier</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        
    </build>
 
  
</project>
```

This is my war lib folder

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you Show your pom file please?

Comment: I bet there is a conflict of JSTL libraries of different versions. Find all versions of the library installed, in your EAR, in your WARs, and in WebLogic installation. Check the endorsed libs as well. What versions of Spring, WebLogic, JSF are you using?

Comment: using weblogic 10.3.6.0

Comment: jsf(1.2,1.2.9.0),jstl(1.2,1.2.0.1) weblogic default

Comment: Wanted to post is as an answer, but I just red your comment. 
upvoted ;)

Comment: I am making my application as a war using maven and deploying in weblogic.what is the need of pom there as there will be no pom available in war.

Comment: @BalusC I have tried with <scope>provided</scope> also by removing jars from lib folder both of them are not working same problem

Comment: Check if you have a weblogic-application.xml file and its contents. This can define class loading sequences. If you have the jstl-1.2.jar in your war file, ensure that you have "prefer-web-inf-classes" setting in weblogic.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is of weblogic.xml.I didnot add weblogic.xml.After adding the weblogic.xml with prefer-web-inf-classes tag .Now app is working fine.I have added spring and hibernate based weblogic.xml with prefer-web-inf-classes tag .

Comment: By setting this value you are telling weblogic to favor everything provided in the WEB-INF/lib folder over what is shipped with your application server. Allow me to disagree that you really want to override the servlet-api. What you have done is a workaround it is not a solution. Effectively what you want is to remove from the lib folder everything that is not needed.

Answer (score 8):

**On Weblogic**, or **Websphere** , or **JBoss** or any other **EJB container** Set the dependency scope in maven for `servlet-api` in pom.xml to "provided". Do the same for the **`jstl`** dependency. ****They already come as part of your application server. There is absolutely no reason to package the servlets in your jar.****

Ensure they are not present in your war lib folder. If they still are you need to check for transitive dependencies. You can find them out by executing "`mvn dependency:tree"` from the command line.

On **Tomcat** or **Jetty** or other **servlet container**. jstl does not come as provided library therefore you need to deploy it as part of your WAR archive inside WEB-INF/lib. This would say that if you are using maven the scope of the dependency should be set to "`compile`".

Comment: Some other Servlet containers, like Tomcat, require you deploy jstl.jar with your War, but on app servers like Weblogic where it is already provided by the server, you definitely don't want to package it with your War.

Answer (score 0):

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:** This error will raise when there is no .class file at the time of classloader trying to load the classes dynamically at runtime.
This exception is also raised when the class file is present also. That situations are,

- While initializing static variables.
- Exception raised while initializing static blocks.

In your case, declare the 'provided' in your 'servlet-api' and 'jstl'. If you don't have any problem declare the same for most of the dependencies. when you are declaring a specific dependency in POM.XML you should verify the other dependencies will be compatible with it or not.

Answer (score -1):

Basically it is looking for core taglib from jstl jar. Try adding below to your pom or replacing the existing jstl dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>           
</dependency> You can also add <version>4.0.0-b01</version> if it needs.
Hope this helps.
```